# ImagePullBackOff error on 1 out of 2 replica pods

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes

I created a deployment using yaml file with 2 replicas.
Out of 2 replicas, 1 is running and other in ImagePullBackOff error state.
I've nginx latest image on my local cluster downloaded also.
Below is the error on describing pod

```
Warning  Failed     9m27s (x4 over 11m)  kubelet, kube      Error: ErrImagePull
Normal   Pulling    9m27s (x4 over 11m)  kubelet, kube      Pulling image "nginx"
Warning  Failed     9m27s                kubelet, kube      Failed to pull image "nginx": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on [::1]:53: read udp [::1]:44322->[::1]:53: read: connection refused
Warning  Failed     60s (x43 over 11m)   kubelet, kube      Error: ImagePullBackOff
```

Deployment file.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: my-nginx
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: my-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-nginx
        #imagePullPolicy: Never
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: check if there is a firewall blocking connection to port 53 on the kubernetes node where that replica of the pod is scheduled

Comment: no blocking from wirewall.
kube-work@kubework:~$ netstat -a -n
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

Comment: UDP also listening
udp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*

Comment: Something is wrong with the host's DNS setup.  (This turns out to not be a programming question, so it's sadly not on-topic for Stack Overflow.)  If you're in a cloud environment with some sort of autoscaler creating nodes, the easiest thing to do is just delete the troublesome node.

Comment: Not using any cloud environment. setting up in my local vm oraclebox.

Comment: Also, In host DNS, I've commented nameserver 127.0.0.1 because core-dns was getting errored and so host DNS file is blank

Comment: Could you please provide the coredns logs from the failing node?